# Why suspend / hibernate does not work? (blank screen problem)

Tags: 10.10, suspend, hibernate

I've got a problem with Ubuntu 10.10 suspend / hibernation. When I try to do one of these actions, computer prepares but in the end a blank screen comes up with just a single underscore blinking. Computer becomes unresponsive to mouse/keyboard and only pressing power button on chasis restores it. Disks and coolers are working during the suspend / hibernation as if nothing happened. Can anyone give me some advice how to solve it? Thank you.

Comment: Could you please rephrase your title to make it a question instead of an affirmation ?

Comment: Please add some hardware information to your question.

Comment: If you would like answers on this, please update it and we can unlock it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which graphics card you use, but I partially solved a similar problem after changing from the repository ATI drivers to the proprietary, binary Catalyst drivers from the ATI page.
To be clear, my problem was that suspension and hibernation did "suspend" and turn the computer off, respectively, but I could never resume in any of those cases.
However, that was not totally effective, since the resuming processes now worked but they were astonishingly slow. Resuming from hibernation could take up to 8 minutes.

After following this post
http://ubuntu-virginia.ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=9378826#post9378826
now it works excellently.

I think it's probable that your problem might be solved in another way, but keep in mind this as a possible alternative if nothing else works.

Answer (score 0):

Updating my graphics driver to ATI Radeon community managed drivers fixed this.